# How does CSS find a child element ?

Tags: html, css

Consider the following code:

```
<h2>
  Working example
</h2>
<div class="test">
  <button>FirstChild (Yellow)</button>
  <button>Middle</button>
  <button>Middle</button>
  <button>LastChild (Red)</button>
</div>

<div class="test">
  <h2>
  Not working example - no DIVs
  </h2>
  <button>FirstChild (Yellow)</button>
  <button>Middle</button>
  <button>Middle</button>
  <button>LastChild (Red)</button>
</div>

<div class="test">
  <h2>
  Not working example - Divs
  </h2>
  <div>
    <button>FirstChild (Yellow)</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>Middle</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>Middle</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>LastChild (Red)</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
.test button:first-child {
  background: yellow;
}

.test button:last-child {
  background: red;
}

.test button:not(:last-child):not(:first-child) {
  background: cyan;
}
```

The result:

[image]

Why my CSS if not finding the child button element if it is inside a div or has another element (h2) in the middle ? There are no other button elements in the test div.

How to make this CSS consider the 3 given situations with the correct behaviour (Working example) ?

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/nedaofLr/)

Comment: It will not work because they are not the first/last child of their **same** parent-container.

Comment: `button:first-child` means: the first child and the element that is a button. Both requirements must be fulfilled.

Comment: Thanks @zerkms for the hint. What I need is the "first button found in the child tree" or something similar... Is there a way to accomplish that ?

Comment: @Mendes `first-of-type` is what you want instead of `first-child`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.test button:first-child` this works on 1st one but failed on 2nd since first child of .test is `h2` not button

SOLUTION:

Order matters in CSS so first set all button under .test to green, then set first/last to their color.

You should use `first-of-type` and `last-of-type` to target first of type (button or div) in siblings, or last in siblings, if you not sure about siblings, you should really read this:

> ## Adjacent sibling selectors
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors

```css
.test button {
  background: green;
}

.test > button:first-of-type,
.test div:first-of-type button {
  background: yellow;
}

.test > button:last-of-type,
.test div:last-of-type button {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<h2>
  Working example
</h2>
<div class="test">
  <button>FirstChild (Yellow)</button>
  <button>Middle</button>
  <button>Middle</button>
  <button>LastChild (Red)</button>
</div>

<div class="test">
  <h2>
    Not working example - no DIVs
  </h2>
  <button>FirstChild (Yellow)</button>
  <button>Middle</button>
  <button>Middle</button>
  <button>LastChild (Red)</button>
</div>

<div class="test">
  <h2>
    Not working example - Divs
  </h2>
  <div>
    <button>FirstChild (Yellow)</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>Middle</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>Middle</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>LastChild (Red)</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, but still not working in case of divs (third example)...

Comment: @Mendes i know, check updated one

Comment: @Mendes reload the page if you don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are mistaking what `:last-child` and the rest means and how it works. It is not the content of the button but the last element in a group of child elements. Your usage is incorrect.

You can try `.test div:last-child button {color:red;}` as an example.

Comment: Got it. What I need is the "first button element found"... Is there a way to find it  and fix my code ? The suggestion does not work property also...

Answer (score 0):

Find the child element

```
.test button:first-child or .test button:nth-child(1)

.test button:nth-child(2)
.test button:nth-child(3)

.test button:last-child or  .test button:nth-child(4)
```